# Disable/move where an embedded video from a playlist populated by php plays

Tags: javascript, php, video, embed

So I can't seem to find a direct way to have the videos in the "playlist" I created to not play in the div it's in. I have a div that holds videos from my data base and I am looping through/displaying them like this:

```
<?php
   while ($Row = $S_DB_Conn->FetchAssoc($Res)) {
   echo "<object width=\"448\" height=\"270\" data=\"" . $Row['url'] . "\"</object>";
 }
```

?>

So it displays the videos very nicely like a playlist in the div I have them in. The problem is that since they are each made as an object to play the video, it plays right there. I haven't come across a way to stop that from happening.

(note: I have been able to make it so when I click on a video also displays in the main div and play there with other info like I want, it just plays in the side div as well)

I assume that the answer is going to be in JavaScript but I haven't found anything that has fixed it yet.

Comment: You mean don't autoplay all videos when page openns?

Comment: Nope. They already don't autoplay when the page opens(which is how I want it). I'm saying when I click to play a video, I don't want it to play in the box it's in. I want it to display in another div. Like as if it were a button to bring up a video, instead of being a video itself

Comment: Are these flash videos?

Comment: They are videos from youtube that I stored the embed url in my database